# 'suspend' does not work anymore after update of ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kernel, 20.04, updates, suspend, ubuntu-drivers

Anyone noticed this 'suspend' issue? Anyone who can please let me know how to resolve this matter, I like suspend very much. After update screen goes black on suspend mode and comes on again  after a 10 seconds delay in the desktop version. Thanks so much ..